# I connected my Namecheap domain to my Heroku Application but when I go to it, Heroku says "There's nothing here yet"

Tags: heroku, namecheap

Namecheap confirmed for me that the DNS configuration for pointing the domain was properly done and could not identify any issues. Does anyone have a suggestion on this issue please?

I pointed the domain yesterday.

Comment: Does the "there's nothing here yet" page look like something from Heroku? Have you added the domain to your app on the Heroku side?

Comment: Yes, it's from Heroku, and yes I have.

Comment: Have you deployed your code to the app?

Comment: Yes, the app launches with the .herokuapp.com domain.

Comment: Does [`heroku domains`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#view-existing-domains) show the custom domain you are trying to use? And is the "DNS Target" that shows there the same one you used when setting up your CNAME with your registrar?

Comment: Oh, so sorry for the late reply. Yes heroku domans shows my custom domain. And the DNS Target is the same one I used in the CNAME record at Namecheap.

Comment: Can you share the domain name you are trying to configure?

Comment: Solved the issue. Looks like I did not add 'www.' when I was creating the custom domain. Thanks Chris.